# Orbit 1.4 vs Flexslider: Issues with each, trying to pick one

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, orbit

This slider http://www.bureauforgood.com/RSTR-IA-2/1.1-Home-2.html is made with Orbit 1.4. everything works great. The problem? Orbit forces me to pick an aspect ratio that applies to both desktop and mobile. On mobile, I need the slider to be much taller.

This http://www.bureauforgood.com/RSTR-IA-2/1.1-Home.html is made with Flexslider. Flexslider allows me to make the slide taller if I want in mobile. The problems? The slides are a random width, they don't line up correctly, and the bottom "Next" area doesn't even show up (see the Orbit one to see what I mean).

Any way I can make Orbit have a different aspect ratio in mobile OR solve all these issues in Flexslider? So far I'm more inclined to use Orbit because I'm using Foundation (3), but the aspect ration issue is a deal-breaker.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the newest version of Orbit for this--the one included with Foundation 4. It solved all the issues I had with both Orbit 1.4 and Flexslider.